# SwingX JXTreeTableCellRenderer messes up my table

Tags: java, swing, swingx, treetable

Here is my cell renderer class

```
    public class MyCellRenderer extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer{

    ImageIcon parentbill = new ImageIcon("images/parentbill.png");

    ImageIcon childbill = new ImageIcon("images/childbill.png");

    ImageIcon parentPurchase = new ImageIcon("images/parentexpense.png");

    ImageIcon childPurchase = new ImageIcon("images/childexpense.png");

    public MyCellRenderer(TreeTableController contr){
        super();
    }
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {
            Component c = super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, selected, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);
           if(leaf){

                setIcon(childPurchase);
                //((DefaultTreeCellRenderer) c).setClosedIcon(parentPurchase);
            }else{
                setIcon(parentPurchase);    
            }

            if(expanded){
                setIcon(parentPurchase);
            }

            return c;
        }
}
```

And there is how I add it:

```
    TableModel tableModel = new TableModel(root);
    JXTreeTable treeTable = new JXTreeTable(tableModel);
    treeController = new TreeTableController(tableModel, treeTable);

    MyCellRenderer cellRenderer = new MyCellRenderer(treeController);
    treeController.getTable().setTreeCellRenderer(cellRenderer);
```

So, my renderer is supposed to change icons for the different kinds of rows in the table.
And, he does it(wow!). But he messes how table should look at the first place, he puts some java garbage in the first cell, like this:
[image: It suppose to have word purchase in the first cell, but it appears only when i click on it]
How can i fix it? I know, there is a method to set icons from JXTreeTable without renderer, but i want to add some conditions depending on the type of the row, so I have to override it.

Comment: What are you storing in the `Description` node? The renderer is using the `toString` method of the `value` object for the text of the node

Comment: I am storing String "Purchase" or "Bill"

Comment: Looks like you're storing an array of values (or at least are returning an array for the given column)

Comment: hm that is strange, i dont store an array of values in description. but each row itself is an array of values, so maybe renderer doenst know where to put it?

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses